# Symfony 5 and edit content with pictures and FileType "null given""

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony5

I have a content management site. When I try to modify an article and I validate without adding images to the input `FileType` created with Symfony Forms

I have this error:

> Expected argument of type "string", "null" given at property path "name".

I don't see how to create my condition in my controller to avoid the validation of inputs if they are empty.

Here is my form:

```
class ArticleType extends AbstractType
    {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder
                ->add('Name',TextType::class,[
                    'purify_html' => true
                    ])
                ->add('coverImage',FileType::class, [
                    'data_class' => null,
                    'required'   => false,
                    'empty_data' => '',
                    ])
                ->add('description',TextareaType::class,[
                    'purify_html' => true
                    ])
                ->add('legende',TextType::class,[
                    'purify_html' => true,
                    'required'   => false
                    ])
                ->add('images', CollectionType::class,[
                    'entry_type'     => ImageType::class,
                    'allow_add'      => true,
                    ])
                ;
        }
```

My AddController:

```
        // Create Form
        $form = $this->createForm(ArticleType::class, $article);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        // Check Submit
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            // Position
            if (!$article->getId()) {
                $article->setPosition(sizeof($articleRepository->findAll())+1);
              }

                // Get Picture COVER
                $pictureCover = $form->get('coverImage')->getData();
                $fileNameHome = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$pictureCover->guessExtension();
                // Upload
                $pictureCover->move(
                    $this->getParameter('upload_image'),
                    $fileNameHome
                );
                // BDD
                $article->setCoverImage($fileNameHome);

            // Author
            $user = $this->getUser()->getUsername();
            $article->setAuthor($user);
            $manager->persist($article);
            // Boucle
            foreach($article->getImages() as $picture){
                $file = new File($picture->getName());
                // Rename
                $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();
                // Upload
                $file->move(
                    $this->getParameter('upload_image'),
                    $fileName
                );
                // BDD
                $picture->setArticle($article);
                $picture->setName($fileName);
                $article->addImage($picture);
                $manager->persist($picture);

            }
            $manager->persist($article);
            $manager->flush();
            // Message flash
            $this->addFlash(
                'success',
                '<i data-feather="check"></i> L\'article a bien été ajouté'
            );
            return $this->redirectToRoute('list');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution for my issue .

**My ArticleType**

```
->add('images', CollectionType::class,[
                'entry_type'     => ImageType::class,
                'allow_add'      => true,
                'allow_delete'   => true,
                'by_reference'   => false,
                'prototype'      => true,
                ])
```

**My ImageType**

```
$builder->add('name',FileType::class,[
            'data_class' => null,
            'mapped' => false,
            ])
        ->add('caption', TextType::class, $this->getConfig("Légende", "Ecrivez la légende de l'illustration..."));
        ;
```

But now , my Collection doesn't work. $form->getData() return null..